# Run Visual Studio Project from Jenkins

Tags: visual-studio, jenkins, console-application

I have a Project in Visual Studio of type Console Application. How can I trigger this using Jenkins?

Comment: Are you using .Net framework? I think you are looking for MSBuild plugin, but you may have a long way to go before you get anywhere near executing it via Jenkins. https://plugins.jenkins.io/msbuild/

Answer (score 0):

Trigger? I guess you want it to get it run when the developer pushes the code to repository and you should get your build rolling.

You can either use Git poll scm. or GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling.
If you're looking for something else, please be more specific with your question.